# Copy files from AWS S3 with access/secret keys

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli, object-storage, aws-config

I need to access a `Cloudian S3` bucket and copy certain files to my local directory. What I was given was 4 piece of info in the following format:

```
•   Access key: 5x4x3x2x1xxx
•   Secret key: ssssssssssss
•   Region: us-east-1
•   S3 endpoint: https://s3-aaa.xxx.bbb.net 
•   Storage path: store/STORE1/
```

What I do is first configure and create a profile called `cloudian` which asks above info:

```
aws configure --profile cloudian
```

And then I run a sample command. For instance to copy a file:

```
aws --profile=cloudian --endpoint-url= https://s3-aaa.xxx.bbb.net  s3 cp s3://store/STORE1/FILE.mp4 /home/myfile.mp4
```

But it keeps waiting, no output, no errors, nothing. Am I doing anything wrong? Is there anything missing?

Comment: Dont need space there `s3:// store/STOR`

Comment: Sure. That was a type in question! lol

Comment: Add debug your command to get more information by adding option --debug (boolean)

Comment: Should I write it as `--debug true`?

Comment: Just add --debug

Comment: Yeah lots of outputs printed...Every iteration it increments and says `Starting new HTTPS connection (1)`...

Comment: Are you trying to copy from S3 bucket to local? In that case you can get the path to your file in the S3 from UI. Also, endpoint url option is not required.

Comment: Only thing I was given was these info. I don't have access to the UI. And I have to do this for thousands of files in code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208877/discussion-between-ajinkya-and-tina-j).

Comment: Do your ~.aws/credentials and ~/.aws/config file match what is shown at https://cloudian.com/blog/aws-cli-s3-compatible-storage/?

Comment: If there are a large number of files, tens or hundreds of thousands or more, then what you are observing *might* be kind of... normal.  aws-cli is painfully slow at many operations and the S3 ListObjects APIs do not allow any parallelization when iterating a bucket's objects.  It's fetch 1000, next 1000, next 1000... any idea how large this bucket is?

Comment: Actually the bucket has thousands of folders inside. That's correct. But looks like my current problem is not related to number of files though. If I wait, I get a `HTTP Timeout` error :-|

Answer (score 0):

If you have set the profile properly, this should work:

```
aws --profile cloudian s3 cp s3://s3-aaa/store/STORE1/FILE.mp4 /home/myfile.mp4
```

where s3-aaa is the name of the bucket.

Comment: What I was given was an `endpoint` (S3 endpoint: https://s3-aaa.xxx.bbb.net) and a `storage path`. So I should grab the bucket name from endpoint?!

Comment: There are different types of endpoints, so it's hard to be certain given that you want to hide the actual endpoint.  The command I provided should work IF the bucketname is part of the endpoint.